# ReactJS failing to import components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm very new to ReactJS but from what I gather the following code should work and it doesn't.

I've created a new ReactJS project using the npm command `create-react-app`.
In my project folder I've installed Google's material ui with `npm install --save material-ui@next`.

I'm getting various errors depending on what I'm trying to import from 'material-ui'.

`import Card from 'material-ui/Card'`

I'm using VS Code as my editor and if I hit F12 on 'material-ui/Card' it shows me that *Card* is the default export, and the import above works.

`import {Card} from 'material-ui'`

If I hit F12 on 'material-ui' it shows me that *Card* is a named export, and the import above works.

Where I run in to trouble is when I try to import other things. For instance:

`import {Card, CardText} from 'material-ui'`

Card imports fine, but when I try to use <CardText> I get the following error:

```
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in 
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: 
undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's 
defined in.
```

However, as far as I can tell they are both being exported the same exact way.

```
declare module "material-ui" {
    export import Card = __MaterialUI.Card.Card;
    export import CardText = __MaterialUI.Card.CardText;
}
```

and digging even further:

```
export interface CardTextProps {
    actAsExpander?: boolean;
    color?: string;
    expandable?: boolean;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    className?: string;
}
export class CardText extends React.Component<CardTextProps> {
}
```

Other imports also fail for me when they look like they should work:

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'

Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
```

But as far as I can tell, it's there...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using typescript definitions for version 0.19.2 instead of the new version 1.0.0beta which the **material-ui@next** refers to.

The V1 source doesn't even have CardText: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/v1-beta/src/Card. And the imports are like this:

```
import Card, { CardHeader, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions } from 'material-ui/Card';
```

Relevant docs: https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/cards/